# Unable to install and use Ruby plug-in on IntelliJ for Mac

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I am unable to get IntelliJ to list and recognize Ruby projects. I'm using a Mac (High Sierra). Ruby was installed using RVM.

After I installed the Ruby plug-in, the plug-ins tab under Preferences shows the Ruby plug-in in red (any idea why?). According to the download page, the version of the plugin I downloaded matches the version of IntelliJ I'm running.

Even then, when I try to create a new project, Ruby isn't listed as part of the options.

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition? The Ruby plugin requires IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: I am using CE, yeah... :-( That explains it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ruby plugin requires IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (Community Edition is being used)